# Video editor that works from plain-text files

Tags: video, video-editing, cross-platform, version-control, plain-text

I have used iMovie and Final Cut Pro for video projects. I find them easy to work with and intuitive to some degree. After I finish the project, I may want to change one word that appears multiple times, and I have to do it by hand. Also, the projects take a lot of space.

I am looking for a video editor where the video project file is plain text, which I understand to be an edit decision list. My goals are:

- to separate heavy digital assets from the light edit decision list
- to put the edit decision list into a version control system like Git and GitHub
- to automate some parts of editing with the keyboard, e.g. find-and-replace on captions, change times and durations, and adjust multiple dB levels
- to have a cross-platform solution for collaborators on different operating systems (Windows, macOS, and Linux)

Two examples outside of video production are [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) in 3D modelling, which generates STL files from plain-text files that are two orders of magnitude smaller; and [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), which reads and writes plain-text SVG files.

I found [this article on opensource.com](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/new-state-video-editing-linux) that mentions Kdenlive and Flowblade, but plain-text files seem an export rather than the proejct file itself.

The closest that I found would be Bash scripting based on FFMPEG for video concatenation and effects, and SVG for graphic overlays.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AviSynth](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page) seems to be the tool that directly answers your needs on Windows. This is a completely script-based editing approach, with quite powerful instruments (built-in or as plug-ins) for reading, processing, generating titles and general editing.

Coupled with a dedicated editor such as [AVSEdit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/avseditplus/) or [AvsP](http://www.avisynth.nl/users/qwerpoi/), you can have previews, context help, parameter completion and similar things one can expect from an IDE.

A completely different approach is to use an editor that has text-like project files. [Adobe Premiere Pro](https://www.adobe.com/au/products/premiere.html), for example, uses project files (`*.prproj`) that are essentially XML files. (Newer CC version have it gzip-compressed, but it's easy to unpack them). Now, XML is not quite 'plain-text', and `prproj` are not made human-friendly, but it's possible to tweak *some* little things like titles. I wouldn't recommend this approach though.

Comment: That seems exactly what I want, but it is for Windows only. I updated the question.

Comment: Did you try it with Wine?

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because the thread got no other answers in 7 months and because I have used Avisynth for a month now and am very happy with it. See [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29137/errors-in-ffmpegsource2-plugin-source-filter-for-avisynth/29139#29139) for an installation guide that avoids common pitfalls.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I used a spare Windows desktop computer. I prefer to overload an old desktop with video editing and compression than to shorten the life of the CPU on my macOS computer.